# create individualized google forms based on google sheets information

Tags: google-apps-script

Say I have a spreadsheet in google sheets with three columns EMAIL, TOPIC and TIME where I´d like to send an email to each of the EMAILs in the spreadsheet containing  a link to a google form that has a question asking the preferred TIME for the given TOPIC in the spreadsheet. Is it doable to create such individualized google forms based on sheets?

Comment: I assume the column TIME would have Data Validation and in the created form the user would have to choose from the different options indicated in the spreadsheet?

Comment: The question in the form should be updated according to the value in TOPIC for each individual EMAIL- So for user a@b.com with TOPIC "matrix algebra" the question in the form would run along the line of "Please provide a preferred time for your assigned lecture on _matrix algebra_"

Comment: So what is the point of having a TIME column? Do you want the sheet to update with the preferred time when the user responds to the form?

Comment: Yes-I´d like the Time column in google sheet to be updated with the preferred time the user inputs in the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that should be done is creating the forms and sending the emails. To do that, I wrote a function that loops through all the rows in your sheet (called "Sheet1", change it according to your preferences), creates a form for each row and sends it to the emails found in column A (in the sheet I've been working on, data starts at row 2 and columns are: A - email / B - topic / C - time):

```
function sendMails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var email = values[i][0];
    var topic = values[i][1]
    var formName = email + " - " + topic;
    var form = FormApp.create(formName);
    var url = form.getPublishedUrl();
    form.setTitle(formName);
    form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId()); // This line bounds the created form to your spreadsheet so that responses will be written in here, in an automatically created sheet
    // You can set another destination spreadsheet if you don't want all these sheets created in your spreadsheet
    var question = form.addDateTimeItem();
    question.setTitle("Please provide a preferred time for your assigned lecture on " + topic);
    var userEmail = form.addCheckboxItem();
    userEmail.setChoices([userEmail.createChoice(email)]);
    var topicName = form.addCheckboxItem();
    topicName.setChoices([topicName.createChoice(topic)]);
    var checkBoxValidation = FormApp.createCheckboxValidation()
    .requireSelectExactly(1)
    .build();
    userEmail.setValidation(checkBoxValidation);
    topicName.setValidation(checkBoxValidation);
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, topic, url);
  }
}
```

Next, you need to [install an onFormSubmit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) in your spreadsheet. You can do this to run a function that will write the preferred TIME the user chose in the form every time a form is submitted. To create the trigger, run this function in your script, only once:

```
function createOnFormSubmitTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('writeTime')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}
```

Finally, below is the function that the trigger trigs when a form is submitted. It looks for the row where topic and email match the ones coming from the form, and sets the time:

```
function writeTime(e) {
  var response = e.values;
  var time = response[1];
  var email = response[2];
  var topic = response[3];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(values[i][0] == email && values[i][1] == topic) {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue(time);
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this is useful to you.